# Are there any restrictions when using a reference in a field of a struct?

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime

I am trying to understand how lifetimes in Rust affect Structs. Attached is a minimal example that confuses me.

I would like to give a struct a reference to an object and then later it is necessary to change this object. Since it is not possible to change the object while it is borrowed, I thought that I have to remove the reference while changing it. So my idea was to define the variable as an option and remove the reference during the modification of the object by setting it to `None`. For the example without the use of a Struct this seems to work.
However, if I now put this reference into a Struct it does not work. It seems to me that the borrow checker overlooks the fact that the variable `string` is no longer borrowed. Is there a way to still achieve the desired behaviour with a Struct?

This works ([link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=16d7c1d523659d6758c27df26bc533b9)):

```
fn main() {
    let mut string = "mutable string".to_string();
    let mut ref_to_string: Option<&str> = Some(&string);
    ref_to_string = None;
    string = "mutated string".to_string();
    ref_to_string = Some(&string);
}
```

However, this doesn't work [link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=59693f8435d2f483e5ca5a6e1dd27898):

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    pub ref_data: Option<&'a str>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut string = "mutable string".to_string();
    let mut foo = Foo{ref_data: Some(&string)};
    foo.ref_data = None;
    string = "mutated string".to_string();
    foo.ref_data = Some(&string);
}
```

Error message:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `string` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
9  |     let mut foo = Foo{ref_data: Some(&string)};
   |                                      ------- borrow of `string` occurs here
10 |     foo.ref_data = None;
11 |     string = "mutated string".to_string();
   |     ^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `string` occurs here
12 |     foo.ref_data = Some(&string);
   |     ---------------------------- borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0506`.
```

Comment: With the `Option`, you don't even need `ref_to_string = None;`. The compiler doesn't care if `ref_to_string` contains a dangling reference as long as you don't try to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing the `string` variable twice. When borrowing the first one is binding the `&str` lifetime to be alive at least as  `foo`. There should be no problem to reference another string that lives in "another" variable:

```rust
fn main() {
    let string = "mutable string".to_string();
    let mut foo = Foo {
        ref_data: Some(&string),
    };
    foo.ref_data = None;

    let string = "mutated string".to_string();
    foo.ref_data = Some(&string);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b2b14d6416b34f1edd44160e6a033a92)

**Notice** the use of another `let` binding instead of mutating the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and also the suggestion on how to work around the problem. However, it is not completely clear to me why this works. As it was written by user4815162342, the `string` must still live longer than `foo`. Doesn't shadowing of `string` ends it lifetime?

Comment: @hochej, it does not older content is droped and it is not referenced by anything already, so no complains by the compiler. What I mean is that you will not be referencing the same one twice, so there is no reborrowing after binded lifetime. I dont know if im explaining myself properly, sorry.

Comment: I have changed the code in [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=947a25b1f4a899edd223ef34145c4138) so that it is clearer what is confusing me about your example. If I redefine `string`, then the borrow checker seems to agree with it. However, if I then (without re-setting `foo.ref_data`) output the value of this field (`foo.ref_data`), then this prints "mutable string". But this string doesn't exist anymore, does it?

Comment: @hochej, It DOES exist, because it is not droped till the end of the **scope**, later after the print.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! I had thought that shadowing variables would drop them automatically. But I just looked in the Rust book and found this helpful info:  
"Note that shadowing a name does not alter or destroy the value it was bound to, and the value will continue to exist until it goes out of scope, even if it is no longer accessible by any means." Sorry for all my questions. I think I have understood it now.

Answer (score 2):

The secret lies in the definition of the `Foo` struct:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    pub ref_data: Option<&'a str>,
}
```

And more specifically in the `'a` lifetime specifier. By specifying that `Foo` lives for `'a` and that `ref_data` has the same lifetime (`&'a str`), you say that your `&str` will live as long as `Foo`. So as long as `Foo` is alive, compiler cannot drop the reference to your `string`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to specify that the struct has lifetime of `'a` only while the field is `Some`.

To mutate an object refenced by a structure, you can:

1. Transfer ownership of the object to the struct, and then get a mutable reference to it from the struct.
2. Use internal mutability (see `RefCell`).
3. Drop you struct before mutating and recreate it after mutation is finished.

Which approach is better depends on your specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the whole `Foo` is generic over a lifetime. That way, when you assigned `foo = Foo {ref_data: Some(&string)}`, the type of `foo` is `Foo<'lifetime_of_string>`. You can set `foo.ref_data` to `None` all you want, but as far as borrow checking is concerned, there is still a live object whose lifetime overlaps that of `string`. For this reason, `string` is borrowed as long as `foo` lives. The only way to do it is to drop the whole `foo`:

```
let mut string = "mutable string".to_string();
let mut foo = Foo{ref_data: Some(&string)};
drop(foo);
foo = Foo { ref_data: None };
string = "mutated string".to_string();
foo.ref_data = Some(&string);
```

Comment: you dont need that explicit drop

Comment: The type `Option<&str>` is also generic over a lifetime, and that lifetime is also inferred by the compiler at the time of the first assignment. The difference is that in the case of the struct, the lifetime gets associated with the whole struct, and not only with the field that uses it.